# My "App_Code" folder in my web isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Bellow is my code in the App_Code folder Called "MyDB.cs". I have a problem with the MyDB class.
When I try to run the code it just break and tells me I have a problem with the "con.Open".
If somebody has an idea for what is the problem it will help me alot.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;

public class MyDB : IDisposable
{
    private readonly OleDbConnection con; 

    public MyDB()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
    }

    public DbCommand Command(string sql, params object[] values)
    {
        if (values.Length > 0)
            sql = string.Format(sql, values.Select(_ => " ? ").ToArray());
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", values[i]);
        return cmd;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here's the Error message:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnsmC.png)

Comment: I think you have to put con.Open() in  public DbCommand

Comment: and what problem is it? Telling us the error message is important to let us understand

Comment: Just added the error pic, the hebrew just saying that there was a problem with the code

Comment: Please click View Details and type the text of the message. An image is impossible to translate.

Comment: ["MyDatabase"]  in MyDB() fill in database

Comment: I updated my answer Jonathan , think that You have to fill in the place of the Database also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you put `Con.Open() and Con.Close() in DbCommand`and the `place` of the `Database` in  `MyDB() ["MyDatabase"]`

```
 public MyDB()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
    }
     public DbCommand Command(string sql, params object[] values)
    {
        con.Open();
        if (values.Length > 0)
            sql = string.Format(sql, values.Select(_ => " ? ").ToArray());
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", values[i]);
        return cmd;
        con.Close();
    }
```